# Count without duplicate in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Data given as per below**

```
Categories
T1  - cells(2,1)
T2  - cells(3,1)
T1  - cells(4,1)
T3  - cells(5,1)
T1  - cells(6,1)
```

**Result I am expecting**

Number of categories  = 3

How to write vba in excel to calculate the number of categories ?

My source code

```
Sub count ()
Size = worksheetfunction.counta(worksheets("categories").columns(1))
Size2 = worksheetfunction.counta(worksheets("categories").columns(1))


For i = 2 to size
Nxtr = i + 1
If cells( i , 1).value = cells ( nxtr, 1) then

Size2 = size2 - 1
End if 

Next i

Msgbox size2 

End sub
```

Comment: You need to update the question to indicate how your data is represented in your workbook - e.g. data in the worksheet, data in an array, a string, etc ?

Comment: What did you try so far? could you check the [mcve]

Comment: Hi robin , it is in the worksheet. I have updated the question already.

Comment: @StepbyStep SO is not a *Please write this code for me* site. SO is intended for those who have code written, but are having trouble with figuring out why it won't work. Please try to solve the problem on your own, and come to us if you can't solve a problem with the code itself (e.g *Why am I receiving this runtime error?*)

Comment: Sorry my bad this is my first time to use SO

Comment: I have found a formula =sum(if(frequency(match(p2:18,p2:18,0),match(p2:18,p2:18,0))>0,1))

Comment: But I need to put into excel vba . I am not sure whether I need to loop to calculate or is there any excel function available to put in vba ?

Comment: Sorry guys , this is my first time using so .

Comment: I have wrote a code as per above , however i am facing problem if the data is at different cells

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a formula instead of VBA programming. You will however need to combine some functions and it's not very intiutive at first glance. But it works fine.

Take a look at the following page for detailed walkthrough:

https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range

Comment: Hi gowire , I can't use formula since some vba function need to proceed after counting the number of categories.

Answer (score 0):

If your categories are as in the image below,

[image]

Try out the below code,

```
Sub countUniques()
Dim i As Long
Columns(1).Copy Cells(1, 2)
Columns("B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2)) - 1
Columns(2).Delete
MsgBox i
End Sub
```